# problems with pip install

Tags: python, macos, git, virtualenv, pip

This is my requirements.txt doc

```
  1 BeautifulSoup==3.2.0
  2 -e git://github.com/django/django@f92c9bd5eb272d537051c114bf57ed3aec132b48#egg=Django-dev
```

I am getting an error when I run `sudo pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

```
Obtaining Django from git+git://github.com/django/django@f92c9bd5eb272d537051c114bf57ed3aec132b48#egg=Django-dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Command /usr/local/bin/git config remote.origin.url failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/nai/.pip/pip.log`
```

I am running Git 1.7.8.3.

I created my virtualenv using `mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages <name>`

I am using a Mac OS X Lion.

I have read this https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/58#issuecomment-1337640 but I'm not sure exactly of the steps I should be taking to rectify the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround in the thread you linked: change lines 114-118 of pip/vcs/git.py to read:

```
def get_url(self, location):                                                                                          
url = call_subprocess(                                                                                                                                      
    [self.cmd, 'config', 'remote.origin.url'],                                                                                                              
    show_stdout=False, cwd=location, raise_on_returncode=False)                                                                                             
return (url or '').strip()
```

Comment: That should print out a message but still update everything correctly. Are you sure the git command failed?

Comment: What I am doing now is a refresh reinstall of my virtualenvwrapper. Seems to be working now..